# std::bind "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++

I am trying to set a delegate for a function and have the 2 following classes to achieve that.
On the bottom is the error I'm getting. How do I handle it?

**Class A**

```
typedef void (*SocketEventString) (String);

class SocketIO 
{
    public:
        SocketIO();
        void onMessage(SocketEventString _cb);


    private:
        SocketEventString _onMessage;

};
```

**Class B**

```
class BoardManager 
    {
        public:
            BoardManager();
            void handleAction(String action);
            SocketIO io;
    };

//Constructor
BoardManager::BoardManager() {

    io.onMessage(  std::bind( &BoardManager::handleAction, this, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
}
```

**ERROR**

```
sketch/BoardManager.cpp: In member function 'void BoardManager::initializeSocketIO()':
BoardManager.cpp:68: error: no matching function for call to 'SocketIO::onMessage(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (BoardManager::*)(String), BoardManager* const, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type)'
     io.onMessage(  std::bind( &BoardManager::handleAction, this, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
                                                                                          ^
sketch/BoardManager.cpp:68:90: note: candidate is:
In file included from sketch/BoardManager.h:10:0,
                 from sketch/BoardManager.cpp:8:
sketch/SocketIO.h:25:18: note: void SocketIO::onMessage(SocketEventString)
             void onMessage(SocketEventString _cb);
```

Comment: The result of bind isn't a c function pointer. Any reason you're not using `std::function`?

Comment: @tkausl Purely ignorance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function return an object that is *not* compatible or convertible to a pointer to a non-member function.

Instead use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
using SocketEventString = std::function<void(String)>;
```

---

With the definition

```
typedef void (*SocketEventString) (String);
```

you say that `SocketEventString` is a pointer to a non-member function (i.e.  a function not a member in a class or struct) that takes one argument of type `String` and returns no value.

The `std::bind` function returns an object of an unknown class. That object is not the same a the pointer-type you define `SocketEventString` to be.

The two types (`SocketEventString` and the object returned by `std::bind`) are not compatible. You can not convert from one of the types to the other.

The compiler tell you this, because it tries to find a function `SocketIO::onMessage` which takes the type of the object returned by `std::bind` and don't find any such overload.

Instead of the `SocketEventString` type you have defined, you need to use  type that is compatible with the object returned by `std::bind`. That's what I have shown above in my answer, defined `SocketEventString` to be a different type, a type that is compatible with the type returned by `std::bind`.

Comment: My assumption was that `SocketID` is a wrapper around some C functions, which would mean that `SocketEventString` would have to be callable from C. That's not stated in the question.

Comment: I think this has gotten over my head im having trouble following the answers. Some programmer dude thanks for your kind answer. But i still cant get my head around the problem. Do you mind elaborating a bit more please? @PeteBecker, what you say is probably my lack of grasp on the language. Not necessarily a wrapper around C functions. Thanks!

Comment: @dwaksman — I was guessing at what your class does, based only on the name of the class and the member function. Sounds like I’m wrong, so never mind. <g>

Comment: @dwaksman Added some more more explanation. If that's enough [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn more about types and the C++ type-system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are the real hero! Thanks so much...im putting the books in my cart now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't use a C function pointer for a C++ function binding like that. Essentially, when you use `bind` it captures some variables to be used in the function call (such as `this`), so you need to use `std::function` which handles capturing variables if you want to bind a member function (because member functions at the very least need the `this` pointer captured). Also, *in my opinion*,  `std::bind` is fairly ugly, and I recommend getting familiar the new C++ lambdas.

```
BoardManager::BoardManager() {
    io.onMessage( [&]( String action ) {
        handleAction( action );
    });
}
```

Comment: Im sorry if this sounds trivial, but i tested your solution and still get a similar problem   error: no matching function for call to 'SocketIO::onMessage(BoardManager::initializeSocketIO()::__lambda0)'. Anyhow I will surely take your advice and dig into C++ lambdas. Thanks!